# Dynamically display posts from Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I need to display all the feeds from my FB account in a list view. I am able to display a single feed using JSOUP library. It displays me image of the user, name of the user and messages posted by user. Its static way i have done. I need to dynamically display all the posts as a list view. How can i do that. Any idea would be of a great help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could periodically poll the feeds.

Use a `Timer` ([java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)) to download new feed item and update the list accordingly.

Comment: How can i dynamicaaly display posts in listview in android

Comment: Once you download the new feeds, add them to your adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`, the list will refresh with the new data

Comment: In JSOUP i directly get the class value and display that in corresponding fields. Static urls it works. But how can i dynamically do that. When i need to fetch the data